# multiple network sockets python

Tags: python, sockets, select, network-programming

I'm creating a python script that listens on several ports (defined in the portslist) and when someone connects to any of these ports, a "hello" message will be sent to them. Currently, the code below creates sockets for all ports in the portlist but only sends message to communication on last port.

Thanks

```
servers = []
for port in portlist:
    datasocket = ("0.0.0.0", port)

    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server.bind(datasocket)
    server.listen(5)

    servers.append(server)


while True:
ready_server = select.select(servers, [], [])


for s in ready_server:
        connection, address = server.accept()
        print str(address) + " has connected!\n"
        msg ="hello\n"
        connection.send(msg)
        connection.close()
```

Comment: for one, you have bad indentation under that `while` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `select.select` returns, `ready_server` will be a list of lists like this:

`[[<sockets ready to read from>], [], []]`

So `for s in ready_server` will iterate over these lists, not over the sockets.

Also, `server.accept()` within that loop doesn't refer to any loop variable, but to the `server` from the previous loop.

Try this:

```
servers = []
for port in portlist:
    datasocket = ("0.0.0.0", port)

    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server.bind(datasocket)
    server.listen(5)

    servers.append(server)


while True:
    # unpack the returned list
    ready_server, _, _ = select.select(servers, [], [])


    for s in ready_server:
        # use s.accept instead of server.accept
        connection, address = s.accept()
        print str(address) + " has connected!\n"
        msg ="hello\n"
        connection.send(msg)
        connection.close()
```